# Using a shared object file build using one computer in another computer?

Tags: c++, linux

I am new to the idea of shared object files. I would like to know if I can use a shared object file created on a computer can be used in another?

I used `ldd` to find that the shared object is linked to other shared object. How does that work when moving to different computer?

Thanks

Comment: When you install libraries using `yum` or `apt` or similar, then that's basically what happens: The library is built on some central system, and then used in many other computers. It requires that right versions of all dependencies exists and are installed though.

Comment: It is a necessary condition that binary format (machine executable instructions, memory addressing, etc.) of the shared object file is compatible with the computer executing the file.